# Simple Code Optimisation

Tags: c++, string, optimization

I am a quite new programmer, and I sometimes have really dumb questions,
In a few weeks I am supposed to give back this big semester project and I would have liked a bit of help for my optimization.

Somewhere I needed to get a Quantitiy (class derived from a double) and strip it down to a just a number without integers and print it in a window (I dont have the slightest clue how the latter works, it was given to us by the teacher, but it's not the problem here).

And so I created two variables to do so, which gave me something like this:

```
int lil_patate=q_nutriments; 
string patate(to_string(lil_patate));
```

And I would have like to set that in a single line, writing that;

```
string patate(to_string(int lil_patate=q_nutriments));
```

which of course doesnt work, as I expected, but I would have loved a bit of help to get something working that would be simpler than the first version but doing the same thing,

Thanks for the help and have a nice day :)
Humphrey

Comment: `string patate(to_string(q_nutriments));`?

Comment: Optimization works at the binary/low-level instruction level, organizational paths, favoring certain execution paths, algorithm optimization, and much more, but this doesn't look like that.

Comment: For optimisation you might be more interested in CodeReview, StackOverflow is for fixing problems but [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) gives advice and feedback on existing functional code.

Comment: Oh, okay, didnt know that,
Thanks for the tip,
Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to be able to reference `lil_patate` elsewhere in your code then you can't make this factorisation at all. If you don't need to refer to `lil_patate` elsewhere then get rid of it and initialise `patate` directly from `q_nutrients`:

```
string patate(to_string(q_nutriments));
```

However, while this may improve the readability of the code, it doesn't represent an optimisation in any technical sense.

Comment: ... I seem to have trouble to find simplest answers, thanks,
And yes, it doesnt improve, but it seemed a bit odd to create new values just for that matter....
Thanks, have a nice day.

Comment: @HumphreyGDavis I've just realised that I think I've missed a key point from your question. Is `q_nutriments` a `double`, and you want the string to contain just the integer part of it?